# Query is taking too much time after adding index

Tags: mysql

Query is taking too much time after adding index.

```
    SELECT bc.billabletreatmentsetup_id, bs.name, IFNULL(bc.charges_for,'OPD') 
    as charges_for_vals, bc.nc_applicable, bc.unit_value, bc.taxtype_id, bc.id, bc.amount, bc.effective_date 
    FROM billabletreatmentcharges bc, billabletreatmentsetups bs 
    WHERE bs.id = bc.billabletreatmentsetup_id 
    AND bs.status='Active' 
    AND bs.branch_id = '9197651b-e2b9-1924-b931-54f13cfc31c0' 
    AND bs.deleted=0 
    AND ( bc.billabletreatmentsetup_id, bc.effective_date, bc.date_modified, IFNULL(bc.charges_for,'OPD') ) 
    IN ( 
        SELECT billabletreatmentsetup_id, max( effective_date ) , max( date_modified ), IFNULL(charges_for,'OPD') 
        FROM billabletreatmentcharges 
        WHERE effective_date <= '2015-03-12' 
        AND insprovider_id IS NULL GROUP BY billabletreatmentsetup_id, charges_for 
       )
    AND bc.insprovider_id IS NULL ORDER BY bs.name, bc.charges_for ASC
```

Comment: Please add a bit more context to your question. What is your DBMS? What is the table description. What caused the delay (indexing by ...) and what can make it go away? Such details will help others to answer this question.

Comment: i am using mysql, and i have three tables billabletreatmentgroups, billabletreatmentsetups & billabletreatmentcharges

Comment: primary key of billabletreatmentgroups is the foreign key of billabletreatmentsetups & primary key of billabletreatmentsetups is the foreign key of billabletreatmentcharges

Comment: Use `explain [QUERY]` to check possible bottlenecks